# why the output is Error message -> Invalid entry

Tags: abap, dynpro, sap-selection-screens

```
REPORT zsaptechnical_test.

Parameters:
d_char OBLIGATORY.

write d_char.
```

Assume that the user entered '!' (No quotes) on the selection-screen and executed the program.

I am getting the output as Error message -> Invalid entry ?
It would be helpful if someone explains what has actually happened .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the explanation in the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abenabap_dynpros_fields.htm):

> The "!" character in the initial position of an input field on the
>   screen deletes all characters in the field before the data transport.

Thus, the field is empty, and this triggers the `OBLIGATORY` validation.